# How to send Bluetooth packets/write requests to a BLE device via the command line?

Tags: bluetooth

I have a BLE light which I'd like to control programatically. By sniffing on the Bluetooth packets between my phone (which has an app to control the lights) and the light I figured out the following information:

- Device mac address: `XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX`
- Handle that controls light status: `0x0009`
- Value for turning on light: `c7e3f68520e8d5ae5acd17760a01459d`

While looking into this, I stumbled upon the (deprecated) utility `gatttool`. According to their documentation, I can write to the BLE device like so:

`sudo gatttool --char-write-req -b XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX -a 0x0009 -n c7e3f68520e8d5ae5acd17760a01459d`

This works to some extent. When I am connected to the light using my phone and execute said command, I receive this response:

`connect error: Connection refused (111)`

This is expected, as I am already connected to the device with my phone. When I disconnect my phone I receive the following response:

`connect error: Device or resource busy (16)`

Unfortunately this is not what I hoped to see. Online I read that this problem might occur due to `gatttool` being deprecated.

To summarize, what I'm looking for is:

- Some information/thoughts on how to make `gatttool` possibly work in this situation.
- A different approach (i.e. without `gatttool`). I looked into `bluetoothctl`, but I cannot seem to connect with the device either.

Any input will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
connect error: Device or resource busy (16)
```

Means that your interface is busy, is your laptop connected to a device or is another tool using it? For example you can't scan with `bluetoothctl` and use `gatttool` at the same time. Unless you have two different interfaces.

Use the following to make sure your Bluetooth is working, where hci0 is the hci interface you're using.

```
$ hciconfig hci0 down && hciconfig hci0 up
$ service bluetooth restart
```

To check your interfaces, -a is optional but gives extra information.

```
$ hciconfig -a
```

To automatically convert hex to ascii when reading a value:

```
$ gatttool -b [MAC] --char-read -a [characteristic] | awk -F':' '{print $2}' | tr -d ' ' | xxd -r -p; printf '\n'
```

In my experience gatttool can be very useful, other tools to try out: `bettercap`, `ubertooth one`